# Fetch DB results from TOAD for DB2 using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

How to fetch DB results from TOAD for DB2 using Ruby/capybara

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about TOAD, the DB client app? If so, Capybara is not the tool you should use as it only works for web apps (browser or headless browser tests). If you want to check the contents of a DB2 database using ruby then you could connect to it with [ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DB2Adapter.html) and run queries using that. On the other hand if you want to automate TOAD's user interface using ruby/capybara then you're out of luck - that's not possible.